# .Net Core Console App Hostting Signalr Hub Causes GetStreamItemType does not have implementation exception

Tags: .net-core, signalr

I'm trying to host a Signalr hub in my .NET Core 3.0 console application. What I coded is as follows. When I run I got "GetStreamItemType does not have implementation" exception.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
     BuildWebHost(args).Run();
}

public static IWebHost BuildWebHost(string[] args) => WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args).UseStartup<Startup>().Build();

public class Startup
{
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddSignalR(); 
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.IHostEnvironment env)
    {
        app.UseSignalR(routes =>  
        {
            routes.MapHub<Connector>("/connector");
        });
    }
}
```

Connector is my hub class derived from Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Hub When the app starts I get following exception and cannot figure out why.

```
System.TypeLoadException
  HResult=0x80131522
  Message=Method 'GetStreamItemType' in type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Internal.DefaultHubDispatcher`1' from assembly 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Core, Version=1.1.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60' does not have an implementation.
  Source=Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Core
  StackTrace:
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.SignalRDependencyInjectionExtensions.AddSignalRCore(IServiceCollection services) in /_/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Core/SignalRDependencyInjectionExtensions.cs:line 36
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I gave up while searching the reason and trying to understand GetStreamItemType exception. Finally I created a blank .NET Core Web App and transferred my code from console app into this new app.

Answer (score 1):

When this error is thrown ensure you have the same version of `Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR` and `Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Client`